# Why are the documents from the C Standard working group password protected?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, standards, iso

I just realized many of the recent pdfs on the [C Standard working group](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/) [archives](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/wg14_document_log.htm) are now password protected! For example the latest draft of the C Standard aka C18 is [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2177.pdf)

What prompted such a backwards move against common sense when C++, java, javascript and all recent programming languages are completely open! What is going on?

I'm not asking if anyone knows the password, sharing it would be illegal anyway, but voiding access to the general public seems counterproductive, especially for students and programmers.

What can be done to bring this work to the public domain where it belongs?

Comment: Probably not as many people as they want buy the standard:).

Comment: Are you seriously asking for passwords to copyrighted material here?

Comment: @Broman: copyrighted material does not have to be locked down and for sale only. Most of the software we use everyday is copyrighted, but freely available. Why do other standard bodies such as ECMA publish their standards online for free download? Does it not seem obvious that the ISO, funded by governments, by definition a not for profit organisation, publish their standards under an Open document licence?

Comment: ECMA chooses to publish it standards freely. ISO doesn't. (I don't like it either.)

Comment: @KeithThompson: what is the decision process at ISO? Any idea on how to change this situation? Any data on the actual economics of selling the pdfs?

Comment: That seems like a question out of the scope for StackOverflow.

Comment: @Das_Geek: It seems on topic to me to find ways to make the ultimate reference for questions about the C language feely available.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming as defined in the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: In addition to not being about programming, this is not a practical, answerable question. This is a rhetorical question a.k.a. rant, and an invitation to an open-ended fruitless discussion. There is no chance anyone will let you know the password. There is no chance anyone  knows "What can be done to bring this work to the public domain" (where it most definitely does not belong).

Comment: I think the question is ok, except for asking for passwords. I also think that it should be open, but it is the way it is, and sharing the password would be illegal.

Comment: When they charged $30-$60 for the PDF of the standard, I was happy to buy a copy.  When they charge $360 (or whatever the actual number is) for a standard, it is too expensive for me to justify buying it.  They've shot themselves in the foot AFAIAC.  I'd rather buy the standard, but it has to be at a sensible price — and $360 is not sensible for someone like me who is not writing a C compiler.

Comment: How about [this one](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2310.pdf) ? Looks like some C2x draft and it is open

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The drafts are password protected when they contain only the material that has been or will potentially be published as the ISO standard itself. Because C17 was basically a bugfix release (no new material) this was unfortunately the case for most of the development phase of C17.

But as soon as we switched to "C2x mode" the drafts are open. The first of these, N2310, is still pretty close to C17, so this could be a good base to work with. (And maybe this will draw more attention to the ongoing work on C2x, enroll in your national standards body to participate!)

Whether or not this "belongs in the public domain" is certainly a matter of debade. ISO doesn't work like this, unfortunately, and there is not much that anybody can do. At this time, having their special international status, they *own* the copyright of the standard itself. But they do not own the work surrounding it, the papers that people present etc, so anybody who contributes might still get their credits.

Comment: Hi Jens, thank you for your answer, I understand this situation although I deeply regret it. The standards can be described as *collective work* by the members of the committee, who as far as I know are not paid for their contributions. Making the pdf of the C Standard freely available would be in the best interest of the C programming community. It does not mean ISO would stop selling it online or selling paper copies. I'm curious how many of each are actually sold each year.

Comment: Regarding enrolling in the national standards body, I am willing to do that and it would probably mean the French one (AFNOR?). Can you share your own experience with me? You can find my details on my profile. Thank you.

Comment: Link to N2310 for the c-crusaders: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2310.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine that it's because they want you to [pay for it](https://www.iso.org/standard/74528.html). Generally speaking only drafts of the standards are available, and even those become locked down after the completed version is published. Your comment about C++ being open is incorrect: the C++17 standard is [for sale](https://www.iso.org/standard/68564.html) on the ISO website, while the C++20 standard (not completed at the time of this writing) is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft). From the [official webpage](https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard):

> **Q:** Why are the C++ working materials freely available on GitHub when the standard must be purchased from ISO or another standards organization?
>
> ISO holds the copyright for all balloted and published versions of the C++ International Standard (IS) and related C++ Technical Specifications (TSes). The GitHub repo contains the incremental in-progress working source snapshots as they are edited, which may frequently be in an inconsistent in-progress state as edits are applied, and which does not contain the final source for any published standards.

Comment: Well, it appears that the drafts are protected as well.

Comment: @EugeneSh. The draft referenced in the question has already been finalized and published as of last year, so it's still consistent with my answer's information about the drafts being locked down after the official publication has been released.

Comment: @Das_Geek: This policy is recent. The drafts to the previous releases are not password protected.